# Erro na função optim

Tags: r

Estou tentando maximizar a verossimilhança da distribuição logística com uma estrutura de regressão. O código é:

```
cov1 <- rep(1,115)
cov2 <- rnorm(115,0,1)
e    <- rlogis(115, 0,1)

yy <- 1*cov1 + 0*cov2 + 2*e
n  <- 115

logL <- function(par, x1, x2, y, n){
    b1 <- par[1]
    b2 <- par[2]
    l  <- -(sum(y) - n*(b1*x1+b2*x2) - 2* (sum(log(1+exp(y-(b1*x1+b2*x2))))))
    return(l)
}

optim(c(1,0), logL, method="BFGS", x1=cov1, x2=cov2, y=yy, n=115)$par
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Error in optim(start, logL, method = "BFGS", x1 = cov1, x2 = cov2, y = yy,  : 
função alvo em optim retorna um objeto de comprimento 115 ao invés de 1
```

Não consigo encontrar o que está errado.

Comment: A tua função logL está mal definida. Ela retorna n valores quando, na realidade, deveria retornar apenas um. Verifique exatamente qual é a função a ser minimizada e implemente-a no `R`.

Answer (score 3):

Na regressão logística a função à ser maximizada é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você for implementá-la no R, ela ficaria assim (a optim minimiza, por isso o `-` na frente).

```
logL <- function(par, x1, x2, y, n){
  b1 <- par[1]
  b2 <- par[2]
  l  <- -sum(y*(x1*b1 + x2*b2) - n*log(1 + exp(x1*b1 + x2*b2)))
  return(l)
}
```

No entanto, o seu exemplo parece ter algo estranho... Regressão logística serve para dados discretos e não para números contínuos. (Sua variável `yy` é contínua). Além disso, o `n` não é o tamanho da amostra, e sim o `n` da binomial que você está estimando para cada indivíduo.

Eu faria um exemplo da seguinte forma:

```
> set.seed(1)
> cov1 <- runif(100)
> cov2 <- runif(100)
> 
> yy <- rbinom(n = 100, prob = (cov1 + cov2)/2, size = 1)
> 
> glm(yy ~ 0 + cov1 + cov2, family = "binomial")

Call:  glm(formula = yy ~ 0 + cov1 + cov2, family = "binomial")

Coefficients:
  cov1    cov2  
0.2138  0.1638  

Degrees of Freedom: 100 Total (i.e. Null);  98 Residual
Null Deviance:      138.6 
Residual Deviance: 137.6    AIC: 141.6
> optim(par = c(1,1), fn = logL, x1 = cov1, x2 = cov2, y = yy, n = 1)
$par
[1] 0.2132318 0.1643093

$value
[1] 68.77538

$counts
function gradient 
      55       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Veja que neste caso, o cálculo usando a função `glm` do R, é igual à versão usando o `optim`.